# .aspx works but .ascx does not... why and how to fix?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ascx

I want to put a ASTreeView web control in a custom web control, ASTreeView sample code is like:

```
<ct:ASTreeView ID="astvMyTree" 
                    runat="server"
                    ...
                    LoadNodesProvider="~/ASTreeViewDemo5.aspx"

                    .../>
```

LoadNodesProvider is the page ajax called when loading a node...however if I changed the provider to my .ascx file, it does not work:

```
LoadNodesProvider="~/ASTreeViewDemo5.ascx"
```

it did not even go through the Page_Load part of the .ascx file
Though this might be related with astreeview itself, I'm wondering what the problem could be? anything I can do to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "LoadNodesProvider is the page ajax called..." What is "the page ajax"? Do you mean that it's the ajax callback page?

Comment: i m not quite familiar with ajax... what i saw is, when i click to load a node, ajax will call this LoadNodesProvider page to "Render" the subnodes...

Comment: Okay, see the answers from Tomas and Porco. You can't use a user control as your callback page. What it's doing is it's calling another page asynchronously using AJAX, and the page is responding back with data to load the nodes. You need to call either a page or a web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because ascx must have a container ie Page. You can't use it same way as Page.

Comment: ok. answer accepted. i used Page.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) to get to the aspx where the control is on.

Answer (score 4):

ASPX is a page and ASCX is a usercontrol. You cannot ajax call a control, so you probably want it to be a page with the control on it.

Answer (score 1):

While it isnt entirely clear to me what LoadNodesProvider is supposed to do, if you want to encapsulate some code or run a process via AJAX you have a couple of options. One would be to create a web service (you could use WCF for this) that the AJAX method could call. Another option would be to create an http handler (ASHX extension typically denotes this). Using an ASPX or ASCX for this doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Proco and Tomas are correct regarding the ASCX file, these are Usercontrols and are not stand-alone objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to use an ASPX page/ASCX control, then I suppose it would be best to create a blank ASPX page that has one placeholder, and then attach your user control (based on query string parameters or something I guess) to the placeholder to render out the content for your AJAX control

Comment: i m not sure what controls you mean, my control or astreeview control(?).. I now added a separate page as the provider page, but I need to use some method from the asTreeView in .ascx... so I have to create another duplicate asTreeView in this aspx to get the method... it still has bugs, and I think the code is quite messy now... I am feeling upset :-(

Comment: In the ASPX page, you can use `<asp:Placeholder id="plcControl" runat="server">` to hold the control, and then in your code behind, you can do something like `plcControl.Controls.Add(new asTreeView())` (assuming that's your usercontrol (ascx)).

Comment: ...i understand what you mean now... it is different from my original purpose... I need to put the ascx to different places rather than aspx... but thanks anyway!